# JNDI look up failed with Dynamically created Queue using JMX calls

Tags: dynamic, queue, jndi, hornetq

I am using JBoss AS 6 with HornetQ 2.2.5 as JMS server and Integrated JMS & JMX with Spring.
I can create new Queue dynamically by using JMX calls from Spring (eg. createQueue(queuename, jndiName))). But JNDI lookup is not working for it, I've other Physical queue for which JNDI lookup is working fine.

code sample:

```
mBeanServerConnection.invoke(serverObjectName,
                "createQueue", new String[] { "myQueue",
                        "/queue/myQueue"}, new String[] {
                        "java.lang.String", "java.lang.String" });
```

Do I need to configure anything explicitly for these?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the createQueue management operation, you are also sending the JNDI address the queue should be bound as a parameter.

I will all depend on what you are passing as a parameter.

Give me an example on how you are calling createQueue and I will be able to better assist you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i've added code sample in my queustion, can you please have a look and please let me know if i am missing something.